# Mouse scrolling doesn't work right, sometimes wont work at all

Tags: windows, mouse, mouse-wheel

This is a problem Iv'e seen multiple questions about but all of them mostly got answered by answers that don't help me, hence I'm asking my own.

Iv'e been having this issue with mouse for a while now. When I try scrolling with the wheel (in any program or window) it's kinda bugy as it often starts scrolling down-up-down-up when I'm only trying to scroll down. And sometimes it just wont scroll at all. Sometimes it just starts working perfectly but only for a while and then back to this weird erratic behaviour.

The first time I had that issue with a *Logitech m500* mouse and couldn't fix it, so I got a new mouse after that (*MS Wizard*) and that one worked perfectly for few weeks and then I got the same problem on it.

I tried pretty much every solution I could find on the internet and nothing worked.

Things Iv'e tried to fix this:

- Getting a new mouse
- Messing around with mouse options in control panel
- Scanning entire PC with antivirus and antimalware programs to make sure it's not infected (nothing found)
- Un-pluging the mouse and plugging it back in
- Unistalling the mouse driver and restarting PC
- Used air compressor to blow out any possible dust or whatever from the mouse, thinking that might of caused the erratic behaviour with scrolling
- Used system restore point to rollback to the time when mouse wheel worked normal

I really don't get it what's the problem and why is this happening. And what are the chances this happens on TWO mouses.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://superuser.com/questions/645703/scroll-wheel-boosts).

Comment: @gronostaj Hm, I don't really know how would I open the mouse (without breaking it).

Comment: Usually, there's a single screw on the bottom, sometimes hidden under a piece of soft plastic or a battery cover. Take it out and you should be able to seperate both halves with little effort. At the very least, it's worth opening the mouse to see whether any dirt is clogging the scrolling mechanism.

Comment: @gronostaj Ok so I opened up one of the two mouses and did what you said in your answer. It didn't fix it, it made it worse. Now that mouse wont scroll at all anymore and the middle click isn't registering anymore either.

Comment: See this https://superuser.com/a/1738963/510540

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same problem. For my case it was that the signals from the transmitter were not completely received by the receiver. The problem was with the positioning of the scroll wheel. The spring on the side of the wheel held it a bit higher that the signals does not pass through wheel. I adjusted the spring so that wheel lye some down.I also adjusted the transmitter and reciever so that the signal transmission occurs more accurately. While adjusting the reciever we should take care that it's positioning does affect the compressing  of the spring. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

YES same issues here with the mouse wheel only working some times. It seemed in my case to work ok going down the page then stop and would not go down any more. Sprayed both sides of the wheel with contact cleaner (does not attack plastic) and then compress air to blow it out. All done with out taking the thing apart from the top side of the mouse!!  100% fixed the concern !! First try!! total time to fix 20 seconds. Fixed 3 mouse wheels that were behaving the same way.

Answer (score -1):

I did something that I recomend only for those who don't know what else to do, who tried everything and nothing else worked, who belive that their problem is caused by dirt/dust inside in the wheel area, and whose choice is to throw the mouse, or to do this: **I sprayed a wheel (left and wright side of a wheel) with a WD 40, just a bit, for a second each side. I know, it sounds terrible, but it worked!**

I hope this will help someone at least!

Comment: Do not, not, not spray WD40 on plastic. You can make all sorts of mess by dissolving the plastic in the oil.

Answer (score -1):

The scroll wheel has "slots" and "spokes" like a bicycle wheel and eventually the "slots" can become obscured by fluff and crumbs, preventing the infra-red LED from shining its beam through the wheel to the sensor on the other side.

Steps:

1: To open the mouse, first find the screws on the underside. Sometimes these are hidden under pads.

2: Clean any fluff or crumbs from the wheel. You can use a piece of wire, small jeweller's screwdriver or whatever. If you have an air compressor this helps, or alternatively buy a can of compressed air, known as an "air duster". This should shift any fluff. You may be able to do all this with the wheel in place or to get better access, unclip and remove the wheel.

3: If you removed the wheel, clean it with IPA or warm suddy water.

4: Put everything back together, taking care to check that all buttons are properly seated.

I've made up a guide on how to clean a mouse, with lots of photos which you can check out here:

[Help! I Can't Scroll With My Mouse](https://turbofuture.com/computers/Help-I-Cant-Scroll-With-My-Mouse)

Comment: Can you summarise the contents of your link? This is incase it is removed in the future for any reason. Please take our [tour] and read [answer].

Answer (score -2):

Go Here in control panel
[devices and printers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnRRP.png)

Then right click it
[Device right clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2RG5.png)

Then select your mouse and click controller settings
[Controller properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjpM2.png)

Then select settings
[controller settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91yZp.png)

Then press calibrate
[callibrate wizard thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imntm.png)

then skip through the whole thing making sure you dont press anything else from
your mouse.

Dont forget to press apply
also I think that the mouse needs at least 4 buttons for the pc to detect it as a controller I think