# Mouse scroll wheel is jumpy

Tags: windows-10, mouse, scrolling, mouse-wheel

I'm using Mad Catz R.A.T 5 and recently I started having problems with the my mouse scroll wheel.
When i'm scrolling up or down in google chrome, steam or anything else, my mouse scroll wheel isn't responding sometimes or jumps up or down which is really weird.
I tried this mouse on Windows 7 ultimate 64-bit and Windows 10 64-bit, tried connecting the mouse usb cable to a different location in my pc, and even a different pc and i'm still having this problems, I also tried a clean reinstall of the mouse drivers, clean the mouse wheel from dumb and tried restarting my pc as well.
Nothing seems to be working and it's getting really annoying, could you guys help me out? 
Thanks =]

Comment: Do other mice (mouses?) do this too? How old is the mouse in question?

Comment: Never had this with any other mouse on my pc, my mouse is 2 years old.

Comment: Since you're having the same issue with the scroll wheel across different computers, it sounds like the mouse is starting to just wear out. There might not be anything you can do besides get a new mouse at this point. You might be able to adjust the amount of lines your mouse scrolls when the wheel is turned to counteract it but it won't be a permanent fix

Answer (score 8):

You have to clean your scroll sensor. Dust/hair/etc. can block its work or it can wok in inappropriate way. You can refer to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AlzIrUSJ1lU) for how-to's. Video is about R.A.T 9, but i think it should be almost the same it fifth.

Answer (score 5):

Blow into the scroll whell. It worked for my Steelseries Sensei Raw.

This has been annoying me for months, and was fixed in seconds.

edit - stopped working again.

Comment: I was convinced there was a smooth scrolling or accelerated vertical scrolling issue or something software that was affecting my new-ish MS Intellimouse Pro that was hooked up to a KVM and shared across 2 win 10 machines. Gave a hard blow into the mouse wheel and it worked! My guess is a cat hair got in there.

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem where it scrolls upwards slightly and then down whenever I scrolled the wheel down. I set the number of lines to a multiple of 5 and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

### 11 2022 (Updated)

It was the teeth.

Over a period of time the teeth on the wheel worn out. If that happens it goes back and forth when you scroll it.

[image]

### 08 2022

It's not just Dust.

I saw on many forums and StackOverflow talking about blowing and cleaning the wheel does the trick. But it wasn't only that. The issue is with the gap.

See the image below, the wheel has a thread or teeth and it touches a small plate (looks like a curved metal in the picture). Over a period of time, a gap creates between the thread and the plate. All you need to do is to adjust the plate and make sure it touches the thread firmly.

I guess this video explains exactly what I am saying. Watch it around `2:30`
https://youtu.be/32NMLa4nddg?t=148

You just need to adjust the plate and it will fix 90% of the issue. The dust is only 10%.

[image]

Also, see this
https://ashfull1979.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-fix-lousy-mouse-scroll-wheel.html

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me.

What did:

1. Control Panel
2. Hardware and Sounds
3. Mouse
4. Pointer Options
5. Uncheck "Hide pointer while typing"

Comment: The ways you tried are all software methods, try checking the hardware and cleaning it (or buy a new one $)

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar issue with my mouse, experiencing both a jumpy scroll wheel and double-click problems. Here's how I resolved it:

Disassembly and Cleaning: First, I opened the mouse to access its internal components. Using alcohol and a small brush (like a makeup brush or an artist's brush), I carefully cleaned around the scroll wheel sensor and micro switches. This step is crucial for removing dust, hair, and other debris that could interfere with the mouse's functionality.

Replacing Micro Switches: The double-click issue was persistent, so I decided to replace all the micro switches inside the mouse. This step requires some technical skill and patience but can effectively resolve clicking problems.

Addressing Battery Connection Issues: Although the mouse was functioning better, I noticed occasional glitches and jittering. Upon reopening the mouse, I discovered that the batteries, despite being securely placed, were sometimes losing connection. To improve the contact, I used a piece of sandpaper to gently clean and enhance the contact points on both the batteries and the battery compartment springs. Furthermore, to ensure a tight fit, I folded a small piece of paper and placed it under the battery compartment door. This action applies additional pressure to keep the batteries firmly in place, preventing disconnection.

After these adjustments, my mouse has been working smoothly without any jumpy or glitching issues. If you're facing similar problems, these steps might help. However, proceed with caution, especially when disassembling your device, and ensure you have the right tools and understanding before attempting repairs.